# Need suggestions about technical difficulties - Drying + Pyrolysis of coal particle

Tags: openfoam

In OpenFOAM by default, the **FireFOAM** is well supported for **solid pyrolysis modeling**. With that in mind, I managed to built my solver for a modified version of pyrolysis (*for dry coal - without moisture*) based on FireFOAM. Now in the case of **wet coal pyrolysis**, the pyrolysis model should be developed [absence of air - no combustion] involving the influence of moisture drying.

--> Drying and Pyrolysis occur simultaneously in different regions of the same particle (however both phenomenon should be modeled altogether or modeled separately) in OpenFOAM?

(I) Basically, Pyrolysis is modeled based on solidChemistry ==> Chemistry model for solid thermodynamics, solved using Arrhenius type equation.
~/OpenFOAM/OpenFOAM-2.1.1/cokeovenGasFOAM/regionModels/pyrolysisModels/reactingOneDim

> **PYROLYSIS**
>
> solve (fvm::ddt(rho_) == - solidChemistry_->RRg() ); //continuity equ
>
> fvScalarMatrix YiEqn ( fvm::ddt(rho_, Yi) ==> solidChemistry_->RRs(i)
> ); //species equ.

(II) In my case, I need to model the continuity equation of drying as:

> **DRYING**
>
> solve ( fvm::div(rhoU_, Yi) == - XXXX_->RRg() ); //continuity equ

Here, this XXXX cant be used as solidChemistry technically, because the drying is not solved using Arrhenius type equation.

How to proceed with this problem further,

(i) Should I need to couple drying model externally ==> such that it should satisfy the real flow physics (Pyrolysis and Drying occur simultaneously) ?

(ii) Should I need to create sub-models based on DRYING?

I would really appreciate if anyone could give me a hint where to look at or point me about the implementation in OpenFOAM.

Thank you!!